# Size of struct tm

Tags: c, linux, sizeof, ctime

I printed sizeof(struct tm) in C using sizeof() operator it gives me 44 bytes.But in man page of ctime it has 9 int variables for time.then its size should be 36. How it is giving 44?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The glibc version of struct tm has additional fields...

```
long tm_gmtoff;           /* Seconds east of UTC */
const char *tm_zone;      /* Timezone abbreviation */
```

Read again `man ctime`..

Comment: That are the lines I missed.Thanks

Answer (score 5):

http://linux.die.net/man/3/ctime

> The glibc version of struct tm has additional fields
>
> ```
> long tm_gmtoff;           /* Seconds east of UTC */
> const char *tm_zone;      /* Timezone abbreviation */
> ```

That's where you extra bytes come from (probably).

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the very true answers of RedX and Adeel, padding inside the structure can also lead to a size greater than the sum of the size of all elements. To prevent this with custom structures, you can use GCCs `__attribute__((__packed__))` feature.